# add new author to book

Tags: grails

Say I have `Author` and `Book` domain classes (one `Author` has many `Books`). The user goes to `book/create` to enter the details for a new `Book`. One of the fields in the form is a select with all `Author` instances in the database, but this `Book` belongs to an `Author` who is not in the database.

What is the best way to implement the interface to add a new `Author` in grails, but keep the whole process relatively painless for the user? This is what I am thinking:

- add `Author` fields to `Book` create view in a hidden div
- add a link which will show the above mentioned fields and a save button
- post the `Author` fields via Ajax to save them
- update the author select to include the newly created `Author`
- auto select the new `Author` in the select

I will work, but it seems a bit of a nasty approach (hacking the `Book` create view with non-Book fields). Is there a nicer way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think placing non-book fields in Book view is nasty.

What I don't understand is the need for separate Ajax call to save new Author - why not do this in the same action that the book is created in? If user chose an existing Author, set up the book as usually. If not, retrieve the author field values, create new `Author` instance, save it and then set book's author field to it.

Comment: I don't see a non-nasty way to implement the display of validation errors for both domain objects on one page...

Comment: Why? Errors are bound to a domain object, not to controller. Do you want to display them as a one big list, or do you want to place the new Author errors in the div with Author form fields?